# Does restoring a database in Microsoft SQL Server add objects to Resource Database?

Tags: sql-server, restore, metadata, system-databases, sys

As far as I know the resource database contains information on all objects in its server instance, so I would think it's only natural that when you restore a database from a backup file, part of the process would be to register its objects in the server's resource database but I can't find any concrete information on the subject and I'm unable to test it locally.

Comment: You might be confusing the resource database with `master`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I hope not. I'm was envisioning the `sys` schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [what Scott said about the Resource DB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/248656/30859) — `[mssqlsystemresource]` — that it's read-only (which is entirely correct; it's SQL Server application data), it needs to be stated that *no* database "contains information on all objects in its server instance". That concept does not exist in SQL Server: not for `[mssqlsystemresource]`, nor `[master]`, nor any other database. In fact, no database actually contains information on *objects* in other databases. Sure, you can reference objects in another database, but there is no knowledge within the calling database that such objects even exist (well, not until execution time).

The closest you can get of knowledge of other DBs is:

1. a subset of database meta-data, which is exposed as *most*, but not all, of the fields in the `sys.databases` system catalog view. Some of those fields (e.g. `collation_name`, `target_recovery_time_in_seconds`, `delayed_durability`, `delayed_durability_desc`, etc) are not known if the database is either closed or offline.
2. and, as [Tibor Karaszi](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/151544/tibor-karaszi) noted in a comment on this answer:

   > The closest we come to "having stuff from other databases centralized" was introduced in SQL Server 2000. In 7.0, you couldn't do a log backup for a broken database, since SQL server didn't know where the ldf file is. So in 2000, MS "mirrored" the stuff in each databases' sysfiles into master..sysaltfiles. And this is, of course, what we today see as sys.master_files (and it is in the master db, physically).

So, even if the Resource DB were not read-only, you would still not be able to find any information on the restore process registering the restored DB's objects into any other database (because that's not actually part of the process).

Also, the "Resource" DB can be found at the following path:

**C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL{2-digit_version_number}.{instance_name}\MSSQL\Binn\mssqlsystemresource.[m|l]df**

As you can see, it's in the **\Binn** directory / folder as it is purely read-only application meta-data. It does not get backed-up or restored (well, not unless you back up the **\Binn** folder).

> From "Resource database is a read-only system database which is hidden from users. System objects such as sys.objects are physically stored in Resource Database which logically appears in the sys schema of each database." I figured that `sys` schema = the resource database and when I do a `select * from sys.tables` I'm actually selecting from the resource database.

Please keep in mind that `sys.objects` is merely a view (a system catalog view). If you execute `EXEC sp_helptext N'sys.objects';` you will see that it selects from `sys.objects$`. What that quote means is that the *meta-data* for system objects exists in the Resource DB. This would be the definitions of stored procedures, functions, DMFs, DMVs, views, the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` assembly (which contains the code for the `HierarchyID`, `Geometry`, and `Geography` datatypes), and the initial *schema* (as in table structure, not a "Schema") for internal system tables such as `sys.objects$`, `sys.syssingleobjrefs`, `sys.syspalnames`, and so on. Executing `select * from sys.tables` pulls DB-specific data from the DB itself. The only info stored in the Resource DB that some system catalog views pull from is static lookup data — from `sys.syspalnames` — which is the values for the `*_desc` columns (e.g. `type_desc`) and probably other similar types of columns.

Comment: Adding just a tiny bit: The closest we come to "having stuff from other databases centralized" was introduced in SQL Server 2000. In 7.0, you couldn't do a log backup for a broken database, since SQL server didn't know where the ldf file is. So in 2000, MS "mirrored" the stuff in each databases' sysfiles into master..sysaltfiles. And this is, of course, what we today see as sys.master_files (and it is in the master db, physically).

Comment: @TiborKaraszi Thanks for mentioning that! I have added your note to my answer.

Comment: Uhhh... isn't the sys schema actually the Resource Database?

Comment: @J.Doe Can you please clarify what you believe is happening with the `sys` schema during a restore operation? At the moment I am guessing that you are referring to DB-specific meta-data such as what is found in `sys.objects`, `sys.database_principals`, etc. Am I correct? If so, then execute this: `EXEC sp_helptext N'sys.tables';`. You will see `FROM sys.objects$` (where `sys.objects` also pulls from) as `sys.tables` is just a view. The _definition_ might be in the resource DB, but the _data_ for `sys.objects$`, `sys.sysidxstats`, etc (the actual internal system tables) is local.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky, huh, OK. From "Resource database is a read-only system database which is hidden from users. System objects such as sys.objects are physically stored in Resource Database which logically appears in the sys schema of each database." I figured that `sys` schema = the resource database and when I do a `select * from sys.tables` I'm actually selecting from the resource database. And since I need some info from `sys` I wanted to know if it has data about objects in a restored database.

Comment: @J.Doe I updated my answer to address this. Please review everything starting with "Also, ...".

Comment: Thank you very much! If you could just do me one more solid and advise me how to find information about the `sys` schema, since it isn't the same as the resource database, I'd be very grateful! At present all my google attempts fail, because search engine optimisations, so I can't find out if the `sys` schema is DB specific or server-wide. So if, say, I want to query `sys.tables` does it matter against which DB I do it or not.

Comment: @J.Doe I'm not sure that there is any official documentation regarding how the `sys` schema operates. But, I can tell you: **a)** system object _definitions_ and meta-data come from the Resource DB, **b)** DB-specific objects / meta-data (tables, users, views, UDFs, TVFs, procs, indexes, constraints, etc) is stored in the DB itself, **c)** instance-level meta-data (logins, logon triggers, server-level DDL triggers, linked servers, etc) is stored in the `[master]` DB.

Answer (score 7):

Well, reading the documentation for [Resource Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/resource-database?view=sql-server-2017) (highlighting mine)

> **The Resource database is a read-only database** that contains all the system objects that are **included** with SQL Server. SQL Server
>   system objects, such as sys.objects, are physically persisted in the
>   Resource database, but they logically appear in the sys schema of
>   every database. **The Resource database does not contain user data or
>   user metadata.**

Given the above and the fact that it is READ-ONLY, I don't see how restoring a database *updates* the resource database.

Comment: So after restoring a database from a backup, its objects will not exist in the `sys` schema?

Comment: Also if it's read-only does that mean that any changes are never reflected in it? I read that if you were to upgrade your SQL server or something, copying the resource database and later pasting it on your new SQL server would effectively preserve/restore your objects and this was the Microsoft-advised method. So if it's read only how can that be possible?